# Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter in IIS

Tags: configuration, coldfusion, migration, iis-7.5, coldfusion-11

I am facing a strange issue while configuring ColdFusion with IIS. I was initially used CF 10 and due to the project needs, I have uninstalled CF10 and installed CF11. After that, I am getting an error

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll" failed

My server is Coldfusion 11 and why it looks for ColdFusion10? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for your help.
[image]

Comment: Better suited for Server Fault.

Comment: This is the tomcat double hit problem. Here is the documentation but it reads like an ancient tome. http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html...go to serverfault and see what they do...Type ISAPI Tomcat IIS (that should get you what you need).

Comment: Thanks @FrankTudor. You directed me in a right direction. I have fixed the issue and I will post that as an answer here for the future needs of people.

Comment: @MarikkaniChelladurai My pleasure. It would be nice if there was something built into the Coldfusion installation process to either 'warn and explain' this problem, or 'solve it all together' by making the Tomcat Isapi stuff an option that is turned off by default, because in my opinion, there is not a coldfusion shop that doesn't use rewrite/redirect rules through the native web service whether it be IIS or Apache. Rarely does anyone uses Tomcat as the main webservice (not that you can't) but because proportionately higher instances of CF10 installs are on an upgrade install path.

Comment: @FrankTudor  The link to apache had extra characters and would 404. The correct link is
 http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html

Comment: @HenryHelgen Thanks for catching and fixing that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I click on the username in left side pane on my IIS window, I can find many options listed. I have selected ISAPI Filters inside IIS section and in tomcat I find "**C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll**" as Executable. I just changed that to "**C:\ColdFusion11\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll**". This fixed the issue.

[image]